# JLabel custom event setText

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So, I have two classes, one is the `Observer` and one is the `Observable`.
The observable has a `char variable`, which is changed and when it's changed the `ChangeTurnListener` event is fired, with it's `onChangeTurn()` method, along with passing that char variable as an argument.

Everything works great, the char variable is present in the observer, but the JLabel doesn't seem to update the text. I've tried using `repaint()`, no luck. Also tried using `paintImmediately()` on the JLabel, and it appears for a brief second, and then disapperas.

What I'm trying to do is simple:

```
@Override
public void onChangeTurn(String whoseMove) {
    System.out.println("OnChangeTurn ran");
    System.out.println("WhoseMove passed through onChangeTurn: " + whoseMove);
    jlTurn.setText("It's your turn " + whoseMove);
}
```

I've realized that it's a problem with JLabel, so I tried using `firePropertyChanged(...)` on the JLabel, still no luck.

I assume this probably has something to do with concurrency in Java Swing.

**It works if I just setText to random text, but not if I provide it with the whoseMove argument.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you update the label in UI thread? pls try SwingUtilities invokeLater or invokeAndWait

Comment: You will have to show us more of your code.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Oleksandr indicated in his comment. In a java *Swing* application, i.e. an application that uses classes from `javax.swing` package, like `JLabel`, a special thread is launched. This thread is known by many names, including *Event Dispatch Thread* or EDT. As @Oleksandr indicated, your code that calls method `setText()` in class `JLabel` **must** be executed on this thread. The class @Oleksandr mentioned - `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` - also contains [static] method `isDispatchThread()` which returns true if called from the EDT. If not called from the EDT, then you can call method `invokeLater()`, also in class `SwingUtilities` which ensures that it will execute on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The funny thing is the value of the JLabel text updates when I'm setting some random text like "blah", but if I provide it with the argument it doesn't update. The String argument is not null, since I print it out before and it looks okay to me. Even with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..); it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code - as @George Z indicated in his comment, it is hard for me to know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Abra 'it doesn't seem to work' means that you see "It's your turn " or just empty label?

Comment: @Oleksandr Just an empty label. I tried to switch from using JLabel to JTextField, and it seems to work just fine. Can't really figure out what's the problem with using JLabel?

Comment: Swing text components, such as `JTextField` are _thread safe_ and therefore behave differently to `JLabel`, hence updating a `JTextField` from outside the EDT will probably work.

Comment: @dynamitem pls doublecheck that you work with the same object. Maybe you've got some code that reinitialize jlTurn or reset text. In any case would be nice to take a look at char generation code.